# Why one Java thread blocks OpenGL rendering that is done in other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl

When I try to execute my Java code that uses Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL) in one thread, everything works fine. However when I start second Java thread that simply constantly prints text (see my text thread class pseudocode below) my OpenGL program becomes unresponsive, but the text is still printed. No errors are shown.

```
 public class TextPrinterThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("My text");
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that OpenGL has problems with multithreading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960407/how-do-you-make-a-new-thread-in-java-with-opengl-support) and [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25413.0) and so on, however I do not try to separate OpenGL job in multiple threads. I use One thread solely for OpenGL and other thread to execute non OpenGL code. I did not find any suggestions on internet what is the cause of my problem, I tried changing thread priorities, but it did not help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because this thread occupies CPU, verify: add sleep after print, see if main thread gets recovered.

Comment: I thought that changing priorities should decrease CPU usage for text printer thread, since it did not help I ruled out this option. However your suggestion 100% worked. Thank you. If you post answer I will accept your it.

Comment: and in java, you are never going to trust thread priorities, it's not going to be guaranteed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this thread occupies CPU,

verify: add sleep after print, see if main thread gets recovered.